# Unable to create new User in Umbraco 7.1.6

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm running Umbraco 7.1.6 and in the Back Office I right click on Users, type any name into the input box and then click "Create." Unfortunately nothing happens then.

I've tried different web browsers and turned on verbose logging on Azure. I've check through all the logs and am unable to find any errors that are being raised from this. In the back office it just appears that nothing happens.

Has anyone run into this? Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas of what to try? This is a big issue because I need to make some new Users. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Any errors in the console in your browser?

Comment: Nope -- no errors in the console and none on the website as far as I can see. It just doesn't seem to do anything after I click Create. I have other users in there from before the upgrade and I can change them fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to replace the Umbraco and Umbraco_Client folders -- it appears that during the upgrade from 6.2.x to 7.1.6 that not all the files were overwritten properly. This gave me the correct view for creating a user and all is fine.

Comment: I can confirm this works. It solved my problem too. I'm not sure if i had the problem to start with because i upgraded using the nuget package. Did you do it this way?

Answer (score 1):

Check this section of your `\Umbraco\Config\Create\UI.xml`:

```
<nodeType alias="users">
  <header>User</header>
  <usercontrol>/create/user.ascx</usercontrol>
  <tasks>
    <create assembly="umbraco" type="userTasks" />
    <delete assembly="umbraco" type="userTasks" />
  </tasks>
</nodeType>
```

It should be `user.ascx` as above, not `simple.ascx` - seems to be an issue with upgrading from version 6 via Nuget, even if you follow the [upgrade path](http://code.leekelleher.com/umbraco/archive/)

I recommend replacing the entire `Umbraco` and `Umbraco_Client` folders and using your source control to see what was wrong before you commit any changes. But in my experience it was only the `UI.xml` that wasn't updated correctly in this single instance, even after stepping through many versions up to 7.2.1

Comment: Thanks :) this was my issue